# SpriteBatch drawing not working

Tags: java, libgdx, inventory

I am trying to make an inventory system for my game, but it isn't working.
I have 3 classes that are needed for this to work.
I have a Slot class:

```
package com.mateo226.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

public class Slots {
    Texture Slot1, Slot2, Slot3, Slot4, Slot5;


    public Slots(){
        Slot1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png"));
        Slot2 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png"));
        Slot3 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png"));
        Slot4 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png"));
        Slot5 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png"));



    }


    public Texture getSlot1() {
        return Slot1;
    }


    public void setSlot1(Texture slot1) {
        Slot1 = slot1;
        this.Slot1 = slot1;
    }


    public Texture getSlot2() {
        return Slot2;
    }


    public void setSlot2(Texture slot2) {
        Slot2 = slot2;
    }


    public Texture getSlot3() {
        return Slot3;
    }


    public void setSlot3(Texture slot3) {
        Slot3 = slot3;
    }


    public Texture getSlot4() {
        return Slot4;
    }


    public void setSlot4(Texture slot4) {
        Slot4 = slot4;
    }


    public Texture getSlot5() {
        return Slot5;
    }


    public void setSlot5(Texture slot5) {
        Slot5 = slot5;
    }
}
```

I also have the Inventory class:

```
package com.mateo226.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

public class Inventory {

    String Slot1Item, Slot2Item, Slot3Item, Slot4Item, Slot5Item;
    String curItem;
    Slots slots = new Slots();
    Texture slotChosen = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlotChosen.png"));

    public void update(){
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE)){
            slots.setSlot1(slotChosen);
            curItem = Slot1Item;
            slots.setSlot2(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot3(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot4(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot5(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            System.out.println("Clicked 1");
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.NUM_2)){
            slots.setSlot2(slotChosen);
            curItem = Slot2Item;
            slots.setSlot1(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot3(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot4(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot5(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.NUM_3)){
            slots.setSlot3(slotChosen);
            curItem = Slot3Item;
            slots.setSlot2(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot1(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot4(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot5(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.NUM_4)){
            slots.setSlot4(slotChosen);
            curItem = Slot4Item;
            slots.setSlot2(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot3(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot1(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot5(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.NUM_5)){
            slots.setSlot5(slotChosen);
            curItem = Slot5Item;
            slots.setSlot2(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot3(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot4(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
            slots.setSlot1(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Inventory/slots/InventorySlot.png")));
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my playscreen class I have this part of the code:

```
SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
Slots slots = new Slots();
    Inventory inv = new Inventory();
```

Then I have:

```
batch.begin();

        batch.draw(slots.getSlot1(), player.getPosition().x - (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2), player.getPosition().y + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) - 25);

        batch.draw(slots.getSlot2(), player.getPosition().x - (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) + 70, player.getPosition().y + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) - 25);

        batch.draw(slots.getSlot3(), player.getPosition().x - (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) + 140, player.getPosition().y + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) - 25);

        batch.draw(slots.getSlot4(), player.getPosition().x - (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) + 210, player.getPosition().y + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) - 25);

        batch.draw(slots.getSlot5(), player.getPosition().x - (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) + 280, player.getPosition().y + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) - 25);

        inv.update();
batch.end();
```

I am able to draw the inventory slots, but when I click a button like SPACE,2,3,4 or 5
nothing happens except when I click SPACE, the I get "Clicked 1" printed to the console.
I don't know why my textures aren't updating. If I forgot some code please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of having `Slot1`...`Slot5` make a `Texture[]` for them.

Comment: Will do but, will that fix the problem?

Comment: No, but it will make your code easier to analyze and prevent bugs from not properly copying methods five times over.

Comment: @Mateo226 For an inventory I can advice you to have a look at this: http://pixelscientists.com/blog/posts/drag-and-drop-inventory-with-libgdx

Comment: I have seen that, but I want to make my own :)

Comment: Ahhh... Noone knows :(